# How to synchronize then() with for loop

Tags: javascript

Here is the code i am facing problem

```
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            console.log("for loop"+j);
               Data.getById(item)
                    .then(function (data) {
                        console.log("then J"+j);
                       },
                    function (error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    });                            
    }
```

When i am running the chuck of code `its printing in console for loop 1,for loop 2,for loop 3 first then printing then J 3,then J 3,then J 3 three times` but i want it should print  `for loop 1 , then j 1, for loop 2 then j 2,for loop 3 , then j 3` order

Comment: The Google keyword here is "promise waterfall" .

Comment: @Sirko  seen it but not getting becoz i am new to javascript. Can you put a code it would be great.

Comment: @AbhijitChakra see the duplicate for "a code"